# How can I get the path to a specific DOM element iterating a HTML collection?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the issue: I want to have nested `divs` with paragraphs inside with different texts.

I want to be able to get the paragraph that contains certain word, for example "mate" I did the below HTML structure trying to obtain an HTML collection and iterate it, and then using javascript, try to use the `includes` method to get the paragraph than contains that word, and finally, try to find a way to get the full path from the uppermost div to this `p`.

```
<div class="grandpa">
    <div class="parent1">
      <div class="son1">
        <p>I like oranges</p>
      </div>
      <div class="son2">
        <p>yeeeey</p>
        <p>wohoo it's saturday</p>
      </div>
      <div class="son3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent2"></div>
    <div class="parent3">
      <div class="son1">
        <p>your team mate has been killed!</p>
        <p>I should stop playing COD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="son2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I actually don't know how to achieve it, but at least I wanted to get an HTML collection to iterate, but I'm not being able to get it.... When I use this:

```
const nodes = document.querySelector('.grandpa');
console.log(typeof nodes);
```

I don't get an HTML collection, instead if I console.log `typeof` nodes variable it says it is an object..

How can I iterate this DOM tree, capture the element that contais the word "mate", and obtain (this is what I really want to achieve) the path to it?

Thanks!

Comment: `querySelector` returns the first element which matches the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through every element, remove all children elements, then check whether the `textContent` includes the string you are looking for:

```js
const allElements = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
const lookFor = "mate";
var elem;
for (let i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  const cur = allElements[i].cloneNode(true); //doesn't mess up the original element when removing children
  while (cur.lastElementChild) {
    cur.removeChild(cur.lastElementChild);
  }
  if (cur.textContent.includes(lookFor)) {
    elem = cur;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(elem);
```

```html
<div class="grandpa">
  <div class="parent1">
    <div class="son1">
      <p>I like oranges</p>
    </div>
    <div class="son2">
      <p>yeeeey</p>
      <p>wohoo it's saturday</p>
    </div>
    <div class="son3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent2"></div>
  <div class="parent3">
    <div class="son1">
      <p>your team mate has been killed!</p>
      <p>I should stop playing COD</p>
    </div>
    <div class="son2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was very useful! and how could I get the path? I mean grandpa -> parent3 -> son1 ?